# Debugging kernel panic in Solaris system

Tags: solaris, kernel-panic, broadcom

I'm having a `Solaris 11.3 i86pc` where I have observed kernel panic after OS reboot. Below are the stack traces obtained in core dump file after the kernel panic:

```
> ::stack
vpanic()
lm_latch_attn_everest_processing+0x45b(ffffa1c09e200000, 80014000)
lm_handle_deassertion_processing+0x226()
BnxeServiceDefSbIntr+0x195(ffffa1c09e200000, fffffffc82166a68, fffffffc82166a6c)
BnxeIntrMISR+0x138()
apix_dispatch_by_vector+0x89(20)
apix_dispatch_lowlevel+0x32(20, 0)
switch_sp_and_call+0x13()
apix_do_interrupt+0x353(fffffffc82004960, 0)
_interrupt+0xc1()
disp_getwork+0x170()
idle+0x9c()
thread_start+8()
```

and the message buffer having related information:

```
panic[cpu41]/thread=fffffffc82166b40: 
<1> lm_hw_attn.c( 663): Condition Failed! - if (1)

fffffffc82166920 bnxe:lm_latch_attn_everest_processing+45b ()
fffffffc821669f0 bnxe:lm_handle_deassertion_processing+226 ()
fffffffc82166a50 bnxe:BnxeServiceDefSbIntr+195 ()
fffffffc82166aa0 bnxe:BnxeIntrMISR+138 ()
fffffffc82166ae0 apix:apix_dispatch_by_vector+89 ()
fffffffc82166b20 apix:apix_dispatch_lowlevel+32 ()
fffffffc820048e0 unix:switch_sp_and_call+13 ()
fffffffc82004950 apix:apix_do_interrupt+353 ()
fffffffc82004960 unix:_interrupt+c1 ()
fffffffc82004af0 unix:disp_getwork+170 ()
fffffffc82004b20 unix:idle+9c ()
fffffffc82004b30 unix:thread_start+8 ()
```

I got [`lm_hw_attn.c`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/uts/common/io/bnxe/577xx/drivers/common/lm/device/lm_hw_attn.c) file where all the related functions are written.

I want to know the reason for the kernel panic and by which system call it has happened.

Comment: *which system call it has happened* Why do you think a system call initiated the panic?  And how up-to-date is your `bnxe` driver?

Comment: I'm not sure about the system call, I just doubted if that could be the reason. I saw this kernel panic after rebooting my system.

Comment: The `bnxe` driver is very old but I believe it is stable enough. I've been using the same driver since last two years. Moreover, this is the latest driver available in the latest SRU. I would be glad if I get the updated driver from some other source.

Comment: "Stable enough"?  It's involved in a kernel panic.  That's not very stable.  But if you've been using it for two years and it only started causing panics recently, what changed?

Comment: Are you doubting the driver to be the main reason for kernel panic? I'm using `bnxe 7.10.7` in my system where I haven't changed anything except that I rebooted this system after a year.